# How would I use keys in dictionaries

Tags: python, algorithm, list, dictionary, key

Hello fellow stackoverflow users!
Let's say I have a dictionary

```
ID = {'1130327': ['Starr, Ringo', '1130327', '10/20/1958', 'Music', '2.05', '20'], '0034728': ['Armstrong, Lance', '0034728', '07/21/1993', 'Computer Science', '3.47', '10'], '7733469': ['Gaga, Lady', '7733469', '10/10/1980', 'Computer Science', '1.20', '40'], '9939456': ['Childs, Julia', '9939456', '12/12/1993', 'Computer Science', '3.89', '8'], '2245338': ['Johnson, Dwayne', '2245338', '08/30/1975', 'Music', '3.95', '2'], '4357349': ['Cronkite, Walter', '4357349', '10/02/1992', 'Math', '3.21', '0'], '8453392': ['Williams, Serena', '8453392', '02/14/1994', 'Math', '3.09', '5']}
```

and I have another dictionary

```
Work = {'8': '9939456', '40': '7733469', '10': '0034728', '0': '4357349', '2': '2245338', '5': '8453392', '20': '1130327'}
```

I am attempting to calculate the average GPA of all students who work more than X hours per week. My program asks the user to specify what number of hours is, and then calculates and prints the answer.

```
def majoraveragespecific(Work, ID):
    averagemajordata = Work.keys()
    IDish= ID.values()

    averagemajorlist = list(averagemajordata)
    print()
    print()
    askthemajor = eval(input("For over which number of hours,  do you want to calculate average gpa hours for?: "))
    print("Alright, let's compute the average gpa hours for people who work over",askthemajor,"hours")
    if ID[id][5] > askthemajor:
        gpas = float(ID[id][5])
    return sum(gpas)/len(gpas)


print(majoraveragespecific(Work, ID)))
```

I'm not sure if I am using the right method..?

The ID numbers are specific to each student and the work hours are the last element for each ID in the dictionary.

I would appreciate a little help I have been toiling over this for a couple of days.

Comment: Can you please explain your dictionaries? What do the keys and values represent?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20450854/how-to-properly-use-values-in-lists-and-dictionaries

Comment: This is the second time you've posted this (almost exact) question -- I'm guessing because you didn't get the answer you needed before. Please give us feedback so that we can answer your question as you expect.

Comment: Also, python convention is to use all lowercase letters, with words separated by an undescore. Use 'id' and 'work' instead of 'ID' and 'Work'.

Answer (score 0):

Well one issue is that you are using the wrong index. The gpa is at index 4.

```
if ID[id][5] > askthemajor:
    # you are summing the hours, not gpa here
    gpas = float(ID[id][5])
```

Also, recursion just makes this function way more complicated than it need to be. Try the function below:

```
def average_gpa(hour, ids, work):
    gpas = [float(ids[id][4]) for hr, id in work.items() if hr >= hour]
    return sum(gpas)/len(gpas)

# prints the average gpa with study time >= 10 hrs
print average_gpa(10, ID, Work)
```

Comment: ids[id][4] should be ids[id][5]

Comment: @Julius, actually it was correct before. 'Starr, Ringo' is a single string.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you dictionary ID should not contains such a level of information.
**Think object**. For instance you would have a class Person (or Student) containing :{ name, FirstName, etc... AND... workingTime} -> surprise you do not need 2 dictionaries.

Rq: **Be specific**, because we don't know what represent the key of Work. (I guess it's hours. But why store it inside another dict ?)

Your ID dict would have integer as keys and Person instance as value.
By the way, ID is not an explicit name. Persons or Students fit better. Even though Ids are the key, the goal of your dict is to store students by id.

**Avoid magic number**. 5 is a magic number in your case. We can guess its signification. But we do not have to guess. (now you see the utility to pass through object ? Fields are named).

You also should **modularize your method**. For better readability **stick to the single responsability principle**. One method = One purpose.
Here *majoraveragespecific* calculate the average but also do filtering. Make a new method filter_student_by_working_hours(self, students, askThemajor): ...

That said, i don't see what the Major dict correspond to. (Can you help me on that ?)
Also averagemajordata = Major.keys() is already a list.
***gpas = float(ID[id][5])*** is only an assignation. 
You miss a loop somewhere to agregate all the GPAs from student who worked more than X hours.
That's the purpose of the filtering method.

The calcul part is right.

Last but not least, how can **majoraveragespecific(" Math", Major, ID)** can work since majoraveragespecific take only two arguments ?

All in all, you should take a look to this link. http://starship.python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html
It helped me a lot to write clean code in Python.

Comment: if you really struggle, just tell me. I can write you the code in a matter of minutes and explained it to you. But for now i'm going to sleep :)

Comment: Well it seems i dreamed it. Or it disappeared.

Comment: I think that was in his previous post. This is the second post by the OP, and the first one was just abandoned without the OP saying anything... so we might just be wasting our time.

Comment: But i'm pretty sure I've seen a Major dict. I think user2324234 edited again its code. When i reefreshed it was gone. But anyway... that's not the main part of my comment.

Comment: for sure, you can still see remnants of his previous post. In his current code askthemajor variable is asking for the hours... haha